# Function that inserts values to table in SQL does'nt work

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I created a function that should get values from input fields in html through jQuery and insert them into the table in WebSQL. It's not working, im getting the values from input fields for sure (logged them) and my function is connected to the button in html (also checked). Don't know what the problem is.

Main.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Open db
var db = openDatabase('customers', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers (name, email unique)');
});
})


function addCustomer(){
var customerName = $("#name").val();
var customerEmail = $("#email").val();

db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO customers (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)', [customerName, customerEmail]);
});
}
```

Html input fields and button:

```
<form onsubmit="addCustomer()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Customer Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Customer Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: The `db` variable is `undefined` inside the `addCustomer` function. Its scope is limited to the callback function that you pass to `$(document).ready`. A quick fix will be to use `window.db = ...` instead of `var db = ...`

Comment: Oh my.. thank you a lot! :D really didn't notice but it's weird that i havent got error in the console that db is undefined

Comment: remember that WebSQL is being deprecated and it's possible to not be supported in the future anymore http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage

Comment: What should I use instead then?